# read.table line 15 does not contain 23 elements - R

Tags: r, input, read.table

here is the code I used:

```
d = read.table("Movies.txt", 
           sep="\t", 
           col.names=c( "id", "name", "date", "link", "c1", "c2", "c3","c4", "c5", "c6","c7", "c8", "c9","c10", "c11", "c12","c13", "c14", "c15","c16", "c17", "c18", "c19"), 
           fill=FALSE, 
           strip.white=TRUE)
```

and here is the text file:

```
1   Toy Story (1995)    01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   GoldenEye (1995)    01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(1995) 0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   Four Rooms (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Four%20Rooms%20(1995)  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
4   Get Shorty (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Get%20Shorty%20(1995)  0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   Copycat (1995)  01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Copycat%20(1995)   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
6   Shanghai Triad (Yao a yao yao dao waipo qiao) (1995)    01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/Title?Yao+a+yao+yao+dao+waipo+qiao+(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   Twelve Monkeys (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Twelve%20Monkeys%20(1995)  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
8   Babe (1995) 01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Babe%20(1995)  0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   Dead Man Walking (1995) 01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Dead%20Man%20Walking%20(1995)  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  Richard III (1995)  22-Jan-96   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Richard%20III%20(1995) 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
11  Seven (Se7en) (1995)    01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Se7en%20(1995) 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
12  "Usual Suspects, The (1995)"    14-Aug-95   "http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Usual%20Suspects,%20The%20(1995)" 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
13  Mighty Aphrodite (1995) 30-Oct-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Mighty%20Aphrodite%20(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14  "Postino, Il (1994)"    01-Jan-94   "http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Postino,%20Il%20(1994)"   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
15  Mr. Holland's Opus (1995)   29-Jan-96   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Mr.%20Holland's%20Opus%20(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  French Twist (Gazon maudit) (1995)  01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Gazon%20maudit%20(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
17  From Dusk Till Dawn (1996)  05-Feb-96   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?From%20Dusk%20Till%20Dawn%20(1996) 0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
18  "White Balloon, The (1995)" 01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Badkonake%20Sefid%20(1995) 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19  Antonia's Line (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Antonia%20(1995)   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  Angels and Insects (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Angels%20and%20Insects%20(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

It is clear that Line 15 had 23 elements. It is even clearer when in the text editor that there are tabs where they should be. Why would I be getting this error message ?

Comment: Try deleting line 15 and see if it fails on Antonia's Line. I'm thinking its the apostrophe

Comment: I only got a warning message. However the name for no. 19 should be "Antonia's Line (1995)" but instead I get the whole entire line as the name like this: 
                                                                                 
 Antonias Line (1995)\t01-Jan-95\thttp://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Antonia%20(1995)\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\n20\tAngels and Insects (1995)\t01-Jan-95\thttp://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Angels%20and%20Insects%20(1995)\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t0\t0\t0\t0

Comment: The rest work fine. So clearly Antonia's Line is a problem. But I can't say whether it is the same problem as "Mr. Holland's Opus"

Comment: On seconds observation, I notice it takes 2 lines

Comment: What about trying to disable quoting with `quote = ""` in `read.table`?

Comment: Brilliant ! Worked perfectly ! My question now is what did you actually do? I never came across quoting. If it's not too much hassle, do you know of any links or tutorials that deal just with read tables and how we can access all the columns etc. I wouldn't want to be constantly posting here. Can I accept answer for a comment?

Comment: it is a quote mark issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable quoting by adding the parameter `quote = ""` to `read.table()`.

I believe the issue is with the various single `'` and double-quotes `"` throughout the file.

Look at `?read.table` for more information.  Per the documentation, you can also look at `?scan` for how the behavior of quotes embedded in quotes is handled.